# Is installing DB2 on win10 to be accessed by C program, using Cygwin possible?

Tags: sql, c, db2, cygwin

It is desired to code a demo C application, connecting to DB2, using embedded SQL, running on Linux. The system in use is Win10 64 bits. Hence, Cygwin has been installed and a C program has been complied to run on Cygwin. If this program is to interface a DB2 database, can we have it installed as a Win application and then, use the C program in Cygwin to fetch data ? I do NOT have option of using ubuntu or docker.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is not supported environment on Windows for C/C++ programming.
Refer to [Support for database application development in C](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.gs.doc/doc/r0023467.html).